# How to add a loop in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS 2012 R2.
I need to create a loop in ssrs to calculate the compliance of ONB to LB
but with a condition, for the total bags count <= 100 it will be 27 mins. but for each additional 50 bags add 5 mins.

I tried the code below but it takes only 27 and 34 min. I want to replace 34 with a loop.

```
count(
    iif(Fields!Duration_ONB_LB_.Value < 
    iif(Fields!Total_Bag_Count.Value <= "100", "27","34") ,1, Nothing)) 
        / count(Fields!TotalRows.Value) * 100 )
```

Can you please help me out in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if 'loop' is the correct term, I assume you want to just create an expression that adds 5 mins for every 50 bags (or part of).

I created a sample dataset so you can see the results, it assumes that up to 100 bags is 27 mins, 101-150 bags would be 32 mins, 151-200 bags would be 37 mins and so on...

here is the expression I used, you will need to replace the `iif(Fields!Total_Bag_Count.Value <= "100", "27","34")` part of your expression with this.

```
IIF
    (
    Fields!Total_Bag_Count.Value <= 100,
    27,
    (CEILING((Fields!Total_Bag_Count.Value -100) / 50) * 5) + 27
    )
```

Here are the results
[image]

Comment: Hi Alan,     Thank you so much for your reply. I will try it